Incorrect type hinting with a generic TypeVar and Pydantic BaseModel
I am using Python 3.9 and I have this code:
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar

from babel import Locale
from injectable import injectable
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TranslatableMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if "translatable_fields" not in dct:
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name} must define a 'translatable_fields' as a ClassVar[set[str]]")

        if not isinstance(dct["translatable_fields"], set) or not all(
            isinstance(field, str) for field in dct["translatable_fields"]
        ):
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name}: 'translatable_fields' must be a ClassVar[set[str]]")

        model_fields = dct.get("__annotations__", {})
        invalid_fields = [field for field in dct["translatable_fields"] if field not in model_fields]
        if invalid_fields:
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name} has invalid translatable fields: {', '.join(invalid_fields)}")

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class TranslatablePydanticMeta(type(BaseModel), TranslatableMeta):
    pass


class TranslatableModel(BaseModel, metaclass=TranslatablePydanticMeta):
    translatable_fields: ClassVar[set[str]] = set()


T = TypeVar("T", bound=TranslatableModel)


@injectable
class ModelTranslator(Generic[T]):
    def translate(
        self,
        model: Type[T],  # Model class
        base_fields: dict[str, Any],
        field_translations: dict[Locale, dict[str, Any]],
        locales: list[Locale],
    ) -> Optional[T]:
        for locale in locales:
            translations = field_translations.get(locale, {})
            model_data = {**base_fields}
            translated_model_instance = self.__translate(model, model_data, translations)
            if translated_model_instance is not None:
                return translated_model_instance
        return None

    def __translate(self, model: Type[T], base_fields: dict[str, Any], translations: dict[str, Any]) -> Optional[T]:
        for field_name, translation in translations.items():
            if field_name in model.translatable_fields:
                base_fields[field_name] = translation
        try:
            return model.model_validate(base_fields)
        except ValueError:
            return None


class ExampleModel(TranslatableModel):
    field1: str
    field2: int
    field3: str
    field4: Optional[str] = None

    translatable_fields = {"field1", "field3", "field2"}


base_fields = {
    "field2": 1,
}

field_translations = {
    Locale("en"): {
        "field1": "field1_en",
        "field3": "field3_en",
    },
    Locale("es"): {
        "field1": "field1_es",
        "field3": "field3_es",
    },
}

locales = [Locale("en"), Locale("es")]

result = ModelTranslator().translate(ExampleModel, base_fields, field_translations, locales)

It works properly and returns in result an ExampleModel. However, linting in Pycharm does not work. It tells me result is of type Optional[TranslatableModel], when the output is in fact of type Optional[ExampleModel].
The interesting thing is, if I define T at the beginning, type hinting in Pycharm works:
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar

from babel import Locale
from injectable import injectable
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=TranslatableModel)


class TranslatableMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if "translatable_fields" not in dct:
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name} must define a 'translatable_fields' as a ClassVar[set[str]]")

        if not isinstance(dct["translatable_fields"], set) or not all(
            isinstance(field, str) for field in dct["translatable_fields"]
        ):
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name}: 'translatable_fields' must be a ClassVar[set[str]]")

        model_fields = dct.get("__annotations__", {})
        invalid_fields = [field for field in dct["translatable_fields"] if field not in model_fields]
        if invalid_fields:
            raise TypeError(f"Class {name} has invalid translatable fields: {', '.join(invalid_fields)}")

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class TranslatablePydanticMeta(type(BaseModel), TranslatableMeta):
    pass


class TranslatableModel(BaseModel, metaclass=TranslatablePydanticMeta):
    translatable_fields: ClassVar[set[str]] = set()


@injectable
class ModelTranslator(Generic[T]):
    def translate(
        self,
        model: Type[T],  # Model class
        base_fields: dict[str, Any],
        field_translations: dict[Locale, dict[str, Any]],
        locales: list[Locale],
    ) -> Optional[T]:
        for locale in locales:
            translations = field_translations.get(locale, {})
            model_data = {**base_fields}
            translated_model_instance = self.__translate(model, model_data, translations)
            if translated_model_instance is not None:
                return translated_model_instance
        return None

    def __translate(self, model: Type[T], base_fields: dict[str, Any], translations: dict[str, Any]) -> Optional[T]:
        for field_name, translation in translations.items():
            if field_name in model.translatable_fields:
                base_fields[field_name] = translation
        try:
            return model.model_validate(base_fields)
        except ValueError:
            return None


class ExampleModel(TranslatableModel):
    field1: str
    field2: int
    field3: str
    field4: Optional[str] = None

    translatable_fields = {"field1", "field3", "field2"}


base_fields = {
    "field2": 1,
}

field_translations = {
    Locale("en"): {
        "field1": "field1_en",
        "field3": "field3_en",
    },
    Locale("es"): {
        "field1": "field1_es",
        "field3": "field3_es",
    },
}

locales = [Locale("en"), Locale("es")]

result = ModelTranslator().translate(ExampleModel, base_fields, field_translations, locales)

This way it tells me result is of type Optional[ExampleModel]. However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error (as expected):
NameError: name 'TranslatableModel' is not defined

I have tried many permutations, including combinations of:

Using from __future__ import annotations
Putting the T before TranslatableModel is defined and use T = TypeVar("T", bound="TranslatableModel")
Defining TranslatableModel somewhere else and importing it

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Your second option (defining typevar in advance with a quoted bound) should work, please [edit] your question to show an error you see in that case.

@STerliakov as I say in the question, the code works but not Pydantic's linter
